Making file_picker and bloc library conform to BLoC pattern
Description
I am using the file_picker package and bloc library in my application. Here is some sample code
...

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.audio);
    if (result != null) {
      final file = File(result.files.single.path!);
      final name = result.files.single.name;
      final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
      final track = Track(name: name, file: bytes);
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      context.read<TranscriberOverviewBloc>().add(TranscriberOverviewTrackAdded(track));
    }
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.add)
)
...

Question
How do I make this code conform to the BLoC pattern? So no business logic inside the UI and no UI inside the bloc. Where should await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles() be called.
Thoughts
In my eyes the provided code violates that there should be no business logic inside the UI. Alternatively I could send TranscriberOverviewTrackAdded() to TranscriberOverviewBloc right away and open the file picker inside my event handler, but to me that would violate the rule that no part of the UI should be inside the bloc.

I think you should create a service class for FilePicker and use that via repository pattern inside your bloc create an event for picking file then if file is picked then you can
Future<void> pickFileEvent(FilePickEvent event,Emitter<PickState> state) async{
  final result = // your file picker repo class
  add(TranscribeOverviewTrackAdded(path))  
}

